# Remove few files from old git commit

Tags: git, visual-studio

I'm trying to remove files that I accidentally included in my old commit (not previous or last commit) but running into large conflicts with other files I want to keep. I just want to remove the unwanted files and keep the ones I want in the particular commit.  I'm using VS2022.

Say my local feature branch `MyBranch` has the commits: `A -> B -> C -> D -> E`.  All the commits are pushed to the remote `MyBranch` branch as well.

Commit `C` has `file1, file2, file3 and file4`. I just want to remove the unwanted files 2, 3, 4 and just keep file1 in `C` both local and remote branches. `MyBranch` is my private feature branch and no one else but me is using it.  If I revert commit `C`, `file1` has lots of merge conflict.  I'm wondering if there is a way to rewrite the history locally and update the remote as if `MyBranch` never included the unwanted files 2, 3, 4.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use `git rebase -i` and `git push --force-with-lease` or similar.

## Long

Nothing, not even Git itself, can change any *existing* commit.  But all is not lost here, it just means your job is more complicated.

You drew a set of commits I'll rephrase like this:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A -> B -> C -> D -> E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
```

It's important to realize that the arrows that connect commits—like `A to B` in your drawing—all go *backwards* and are *part of* the *later* commit.  That's necessary, because once commit `A` is made, it cannot be changed.  It contains an arrow pointing backwards to the last commit on the branch from which you started your branch `MyBranch`—the one I used `●` for above—and it will forever point backwards to that commit.  So a more accurate drawing looks like this:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A <-B <-C <-D <-E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
```

(where we're lazy and don't draw the earlier commits' arrows correctly, in part because my up-and-left arrows like `↖︎` and `⬉` and `⇱` just look kind of crappy).  Besides these backwards-pointing "arrows" coming out of each commit, every commit contains a full snapshot of *every* file,<sup>1</sup> so it's likely that the files you added in commit `C`, that you don't want, also exist in commits `D` and `E`.

In any case, the ultimate problem here is that you literally *cannot* change commit `C`.  It will always have those files and always point back to `B`.  Commit `D` will always have whatever it has and will always point back to `C`, and commit `E` will always have whatever *it* has, and will always point back to `D`.  But ... what if you extracted commit `C`, *fixed things up*, and made a *new and improved* commit.  Let's call this new-and-improved commit `C'`, and draw it in:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'  <-- improved-branch
```

Now we want to take existing commit `D` and improve it very similarly: new commit `D'`, our copy of existing `D`, should do to `C'` whatever `D` did to `C`, and should point backwards to `C'`:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'-D'  <-- improved-branch
```

We repeat once more for commit `E` to get:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'-D'-E'  <-- improved-branch
```

and then we get rid of the name `improved-branch` and make the name `MyBranch` find commit `E'` instead of finding commit `E`:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'-D'-E'  <-- MyBranch
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Each commit:

- is numbered, with a big, ugly, random-looking (but entirely *not* random), cryptographic-checksum *hash ID;*
- is immutable;
- contains two things: a full snapshot of every file, and some metadata.

The metadata give stuff like the name and email address of the author of the commit and the date-and-time for when they made it.  It includes the log message they (you) wrote at that time.  And, to make those "arrows", each commit has a *list of previous commit hash IDs*.  Most commits have exactly one entry in this list, and that's our "arrow" coming out of the commit: the hash ID lets Git use *this* commit to find the *previous* commit.

Since each commit holds a full snapshot of *every* file—with the file contents de-duplicated within and across commits—Git can simply *compare* the snapshots in `A` and `B`, for instance, to see which files are the same and which are different.  Git then shows you only the *different* files, and does that by computing a `git diff` to show you, rather than showing you the entirety of each file in each commit.  But that diff is not what the commit *stores*.  It actually has a full copy of every file (with the de-duplication taking care of the obvious objection, that this would fill up your disk way too fast).

---

#### Using `git rebase` to get this far

The command that actually copies commits (e.g., to turn `E` into `E'`) is `git cherry-pick`, but we have to use it multiple times—three, in this case.  We'd like Git's power tool here, and that's Git's *interactive rebase*.  We run:

```
git switch MyBranch     # or git checkout MyBranch, if/as needed
```

and then:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3    # 3 here means "count back 3 times from `E`
```

This brings up an instruction sheet that has three `pick` commands.  These correspond to running `git cherry-pick`, which is Git's built-in command for making a copy of some commit.  We don't want a *full* copy of `C` though, so we have to change that first `pick` command to `edit`, then write out this set of instructions and exit the editor,<sup>2</sup> which makes `git rebase` start the whole process and do the first cherry-pick, but then stop for amending.  We can now run:

```
git rm file2 file3 file4
```

and then:

```
git commit --amend
```

(which is a bit of a lie,<sup>2</sup> but gets us `C'`) and then:

```
git rebase --continue
```

which finishes the job—the remaining two commits are still marked `pick`—and gets us the desired result:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'-D'-E'  <-- MyBranch
```

---

<sup>2</sup>With some editors, you don't actually *exit* the editor, you just have the editor signal back to Git that the instruction sheet is done.  The details depend on your editor.  The `git commit` command, which brings up an editor for you to write your commit log message, works the same way, so whatever you are using for that—as long as it is not `-m` or something—will work here as well.

<sup>3</sup>Git cannot change any existing commit, and `git commit --amend` is no different.  That's why `--amend` is a lie.  What `--amend` does is:

- make a new commit, wherever we are now, but
- instead of having the new commit point backwards to the *current* commit, have it point backwards to the current commit's *parent(s)*.

Also, `git rebase -i` will "cheat" if it can and not actually *copy* a commit, if that's possible.  So when we changed `pick` to `edit` and wrote out the instructions and exited, Git didn't actually bother to *copy* `C`.  It just got us into "detached HEAD" mode with `C` being the *current commit*, like this:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B   D--E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
              \ /
               C   <-- HEAD
```

Our `git commit --amend` uses whatever is in Git's *index* aka *staging area*, so `git rm file2 file3 file4` updates that and then we run the `git commit --amend` command.  This makes new `C'` with the same parent that `C` has—i.e., `B`—and points `HEAD` to `C'`:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'  <-- HEAD
```

When we run `git rebase --continue`, Git picks up from wherever it left off in the instructions.  That has two more `pick` commands, for `D` and `E`, so the rebase now does normal cherry-picks for these: no shortcut is allowed here.  So at the end of the cherry-picking sequence, rebase has:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- MyBranch, origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'-D'-E'  <-- HEAD
```

Now that rebase has reached the end of the instructions successfully, it yanks the branch name `MyBranch` off of wherever it was before (commit `E`) and pastes it on here (at `E'`), then "re-attaches" Git's `HEAD`:

```
...--o--●   <-- main
         \
          A--B--C--D--E   <-- origin/MyBranch
              \
               C'-D'-E'  <-- MyBranch (HEAD)
```

which is how I usually draw these things.

---

#### Your own repository is now repaired; GitHub's is not, yet

You now have the commits you want (plus some you don't want, but you cannot do anything about that) in *your* repository.  You now need to send the *new* commits to GitHub, so that they can put them in *their* repository (the one you control over there).  They don't exist there yet.

Normally you would just run:

```
git push origin MyBranch
```

which would have your Git call up their Git, enumerate any commits you have that they don't—in this case that's `C'`, `D'`, and `E'`—and send those commits and ask them to set their name `MyBranch`, which your Git remembers as `origin/MyBranch`.

If you do this now, though, you'll see the commits *do* get sent, but then GitHub *rejects the request to update the name `MyBranch`:*

```
 ! [rejected]    MyBranch -> MyBranch (non-fast-forward)
```

This is Git's way of saying "they complained that if they obeyed your polite request to update their `MyBranch`, they'd lose some commits off the end".  The commits they would lose are, of course, commits `C-D-E`: exactly the ones you *want* them to lose.

To *make* them give up those commits, you need to use one of the "force" variants of `git push`, so that instead of sending a *please, if it's OK, update your name `MyBranch`* **request**, you send an *update your name `MyBranch`!  Do it **now**, dammit!* **command**.  That's `git push --force`.

To be more careful—which in this case you won't need, but it's usually wise to be careful with sharp saws like `--force`—you can use `--force-with-lease`.  This sends, instead of either a polite request *or* an overriding command, a compromise: *I think your branch name `MyBranch` identifies commit _______ (fill in the blank with the hash ID for `E`).  If I'm right, change it to _______ (fill in the blank with another hash ID, this time for `E'`), even if that loses commits off the end of the branch.  Let me know whether you did it.*  They will now make this check.  Note that your Git supplies the hash ID for `E` based on your `origin/MyBranch` name, and supplies the hash for `E'` based on the fact that you ran:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin MyBranch
```

That is, the name `MyBranch` here supplied both hash IDs: one directly, and one via your Git looking up your `origin/` variant of that name.

Using `--force-with-lease` takes care of the problem that occurs with a *shared* GitHub (or other site) repository to which multiple people might push commits.  If *someone else* added on a commit `F` while you were fixing `C-D-E` to become `C'-D'-E'`, your `git push --force-with-lease origin MyBranch` would fail, because your Git would send the hash ID of `E` when they actually now hold the hash ID of `F`.  You can then run `git fetch` to obtain the new commit(s) and `git cherry-pick` them to your updated branch and try the `--force-with-lease` again.

Since nobody else is writing to this GitHub repository, you don't *need* the `--force-with-lease`, but it's good to know about.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I learned a lot from your answer.  Can I use the commit hash id instead of `HEAD~3` when rebasing?

Comment: @StackUndefined: yes, in general, any of <name, hash ID, relative expression, search expression from gitrevisions documentation, etc> all work. (There are specific exceptions to that rule, such as `git switch` or `git checkout` needs a *branch* name to put you on that branch, of course.) Just be sure to use the hash ID of the first commit you *don't* want copied: Git starts from the end and works backwards and stops at the point you specify.